# Space of smooth functions with compact support.

Tags: notation

Quick question regarding the generally accepted definition for a space.

Suppose we consider the space $C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ of smooth functions of with compact support in $\Omega$, do we generally require strict containment of the support in $\Omega$, or do we allow the support to coincide with $\Omega$ in the case of a compact set $\Omega$ and the space to be equivalent to $C^{\infty} (\Omega)$.

Comment: I think that you allow the equality when it is possible.

Comment: But for your last sentence you don't only need $\Omega$ closed ($\mathbb R^n$ is closed...),  you need really $\Omega$ compact.

Comment: Yes, you are indeed correct regarding the last sentence. I will update.

Comment: So for your question, the answer is no, we do not require a strict containment, the only thing required is that $\{x | f(x)\neq 0\}$'s closure is compact.

Comment: Could you perhaps point me to a reference that notes this fact? I want to be sure I am using the notation correctly when defining the distributional derivative. It would seem that the definition of the weak derivative will loose its meaning if we use $C^{\infty}_{0}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is compact.

Comment: Ok, let me two minutes :)

Comment: http://ruangbacafmipa.staff.ub.ac.id/files/2012/02/Real-and-Complex-Analysis-by-Walter-Rudin.pdf


Page 38.

The notation $C_c$ is your $C_0$ (in fact $C_0$, is used when $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ for my experience)

Comment: What makes you think one would exclude the posibility that the support coincides with $\Omega$? I'd expect in general that smooth functions with compact support means precisely that.

Comment: These spaces seem to generally be used in cases where we require the property that they are 0 within some neighborhood the boundary of the domain. In the case of a closed set this property is lost and hence, before I note this in the report I am writing, I wanted to ensure that my understanding was correct. 

It would seem that in this case, distributional derivatives over a closed set should therefore make use of smooth functions with compact support over the appropriate open set instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support of a function is closed, by definition.

Every closed subset of a compact set is compact.

So, if $\Omega$ is a compact set, the subscript is pointless. Just write $C^\infty (\Omega)$ then. Better yet, write $C^\infty(K)$ because the letter $K$ is typically associated with compact sets, while $\Omega$ is associated with open sets.

Generally, to work with notions of smoothness in a closed set, one assumes the existence of a larger open set on which  smoothness holds.

Comment: Thanks, you would have to however write $C^{\infty}(K)$.